# How Do I Add A Push Pin

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps

I have created a map to a location following this tutorial [Here](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android)

But no matter what I do I cannot add the push pin, when I get to here "To add a marker to the map, you first need to define a class that extends the Overlay class:"

I get stuck, I have tried to add a MapOverlay following the HelloGoogleMaps tutorial on android developers to add the overlay but I get errors all over the place, can anyone point in the right direction or suggest a tutrorial or provide a link to source code that might help, my code is below;

```
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView.LayoutParams;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class GoogleMaps extends MapActivity 
{    
    MapView mapView; 
    MapController mc;
    GeoPoint p;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        LinearLayout zoomLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.zoom);  
        View zoomView = mapView.getZoomControls(); 

        zoomLayout.addView(zoomView, 
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
        mapView.displayZoomControls(true);

        mc = mapView.getController();
        String coordinates[] = {" 53.804224", "-1.759057"};
        double lat = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
        double lng = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);

        p = new GeoPoint(
            (int) (lat * 1E6), 
            (int) (lng * 1E6));

        mc.animateTo(p);
        mc.setZoom(17); 
        mapView.invalidate();
        mapView.setSatellite(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

At this point when I try to add a mapoverlay as in the HelloGoogleMaps tutorial it either crashes or I get errors.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Here is a sample project showing a map with an overlay with four pins: http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Maps/NooYawk/